# Google Docs: changing formatting of normal text without affecting automatically affecting headings

Tags: google-docs, formatting

Applying a change to the indentation of normal formatting (e.g. first line indent) in google docs results in an automatic change to the indentation settings of all the other styles. It seems they have a basic inheritance from 'normal text'. Is there any way to get around this "feature" and ensure that changing 'normal text' only changes 'normal text' and not everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Although a rather clunky workaround, the "auto" ("inherited") indentation on each heading can be undone, and the option "Update 'Heading N' to match" used after each corrective de-dent.  The updated normal text and all the heading styles will be retained.

I used the bottom of a document as a scratch working space to do this quickly, then deleted the test six headings and paragraph:

```
Heading 1
Heading 2
Head...
Heading 6
Paragraph text here.
```